# Can Qt Creator recognize TODO and FIXME comments?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, todo

Is there a way to make Qt Creator recognize TODO and FIXME comments, so that I can access a compiled list somewhere of all these comments?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, go to **Help / About Plugins...** menu, under the **Utilities** section you will find the **Todo** plugin, so you simply have to enable it. After restarting Qt Creator you will see the **To-Do Entries** button on the bottom of the main window, which opens up a panel listing all TODO, FIXME and so on comments.

The plugin has some minor issues, the one I remember is that international characters are not displayed correctly, but in general it works quite well.

Comment: You can edit the list of tags under: Tools -> Options -> To-Do

Comment: Note that the Plugin needs correct casing. It will only highlight TODO. todo, Todo, ToDo would have to be added manually (which is very easy).

Comment: As of Qt Creator 4.14.2, the relevant comments are not highlighted in the code window, they look just like regular comments. Don't know if this is a regression or if it never actually highlighted them. Having a "Todo entries" tab at the bottom of the window is better than nothing, though.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Todo plugin which enables this feature. It is included since version 2.5 (https://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/05/09/qt-creator-2-5-0-released/)